# two event listeners single function if boths are triggered still one call only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I want my code to listen both events but I dont want to trigger twice and dont want to call the action twice.. Because actually its the same action but I think prestashop.on('updateCart' listener wont trigger on some browsers. I dont know, I am seeing missing data because of it..
you can think as

if its triggered prestashop.on('updateCart' **OR** $( "#addtocart" ).on( "click" => call the function

```
    prestashop.on('updateCart', function(params) {
addtocartpixelfunction();
    });
$( "#addtocart" ).on( "click", function() {
  addtocartpixelfunction();
});
```

Comment: Why do not just use onclick?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work. Add a sentinel variable to avoid double calling the function:

```
let sentinel = 0;

prestashop.on('updateCart', function(params) {
    if (sentinel === 1 || !sentinel) {
        sentinel = 1;
        addtocartpixelfunction();
    }
});
$( "#addtocart" ).on( "click", function() {
    if (sentinel === 2 || !sentinel) {
        sentinel = 2;
        addtocartpixelfunction();
    }
});
```